# Map compatability issue with move_base and gmapping

Tags: navigation, move-base, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One more quick question when I run gmapping, I am getting a cool map but when I try to run move_base I get the following error:

> [ERROR] [1304145896.391400959, 492.700000000]: Client [/move_base_node] wants topic /odom to have datatype/md5sum [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7], but our version has [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped/953b798c0f514ff060a53a3498ce6246]. Dropping connection.

Obviously move_base is expecting a md5sum but gmapping doesn't provide it as far as I know, any way to change it?

thanks,
BM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9852/map-compatability-issue-with-move_base-and-gmapping.../) by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "/odom" topic is provided by the robot, not gmapping or move_base. The "/odom" information is needed by the base_local_planner portion of move_base, whereas gmapping uses only the laser scan and tf information.

How is your robot publishing /odom? Have you seen this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2